# I can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, raid

I managed to install Ubuntu onto a NVM SSD on AHCI mode. Alongside Win 10. Win 10 was pre-installed, has a boot loader in the UEFI, and in the UEFI there is nothing named Linux to begin with.
This is the boot order in the UEFI: UEFI USB CD/DVD, UEFI USB Key, UEFI CD/DVD, UEFI Hard Disk: Windows Boot Manager, UEFI USB Hard Disk, UEFI USB Floppy and UEFI Network.
First I created the Ubuntu CD. Then, I changed to AHCI. Then I went to the UEFI and changed to CD USB (where Linux install is) to the first to boot-order. Then I installed.
I did use boot-repair but it's still not showing GRUB.
Windows boots without problem in both AHCI and RAID, but even after using the tool it still doesn't show GRUB.
Also, it's a MSI Infinte A.
Windows is booting correctly with both AHCI and RAID. I had AHCI enabled when I installed Ubuntu, because when I tried with RAID , the installation program couldn't find the NVM SSD... The Boot-Repair program told me to check if there is any nvme0n1p1 in boot order and to type in this in the CMD on Windows: bcdedit /set -bootmgr- path /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
Summary report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rntDSkqD2h/

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Well thanks, but I'm really a complete beginner and I will not figure this out by reading the Wikipedia... This may be too advanced for me.